# Should JSON files have a new line at the bottom

Tags: json, format

Speaking strictly about well-formatted, should JSON files end with a new line? I'm having several discussions with my team about having the benefits of adding a [new line at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-text-files-end-with-a-newline)